# Does ModelSim support program blocks?

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

When running the following trivial code with ModelSim 10.1d

```
program test;

  initial begin
    $display("hello world");
  end

endprogram
```

I'm seeing `Error loading design`. The issue can be reproduced here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/807

I know that ModelSim does not support SV assertions/coverage, but what about `program` blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModelSim does not support the following SystemVerilog constructs that are supported in Questa:

1. program blocks
2. assertions
3. covergroups
4. randomize()

In any case, I do not recommend the use of `program` blocks for any user. See http://go.mentor.com/programblocks

Comment: Use a `module`. You should also read my DVCon paper: http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it does not. If you add an instance of the program block from your example and attempt to run it, it gives this error:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3904) SystemVerilog Program Blocks are not supported in Modelsim PE.
```

Updated example here posted here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/474/810